# Laravel problema con tabla pivote

Tags: laravel, pivot, relaciones

Tengo dos tablas: una de viajes y otra de clientes. En la tabla pivote se relaciona una con otra en ManyToMany.

En la migration de la tabla pivote tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomerTourTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customer_tour', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            /** Satisfacción */
            $table->char('satisfaccion', 1);
            /** Los campos de fechas */
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            /** La definición de los campos que se usarán como claves foráneas */
            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('tour_id')->unsigned();
            /** La declaración de las claves foráneas en los campos necesarios. */
            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
            $table->foreign('tour_id')->references('id')->on('tours');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customer_tour');
    }
}
```

Lo que me importa es el campo satisfacción, donde se anotará el grado de satisfacción del cliente con el viaje. En la factory tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\CustomerTour::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'satisfaccion' => $faker->randomElement(['A', 'B', 'C'])
    ];
});
```

En el modelo de `Tour.php` (el de los viajes) he añadido lo siguiente (solo el método `customers`):

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)->withTimeStamps()->using('App\CustomerTour')->withPivot('satisfaccion');
}
```

En el modelo de clientes (`Customer.php`) tengo el método `tours` asi;

```
public function tours()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Tour::class)->withTimeStamps()->using('App\CustomerTour')->withPivot('satisfaccion');
}
```

El modelo `CustomerTour.php` (el de la tabla pivote) es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CustomerTour extends Pivot
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'satisfaccion',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
    protected $attributes = [
        'satisfaccion'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

Por último, el `DatabaseSeeder.php` me queda así:

```
<?php

use App\Operator;
use App\Tour;
use App\Customer;
use App\CustomerTour;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory (Operator::class, 20)->create();
        $customers = factory (Customer::class, 300)->create();
        factory (Tour::class, 100)
        ->create()
            ->each(function ($tour) use ($customers)
                {
                    $tour->customers()
                        ->attach($customers
                            ->random(mt_rand(10, 40))
                            ->pluck('id')
                        );
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Todo funciona bien, excepto el campo `satisfaccion` de la tabla pivote, que me lo rellena a `NULL`, en vez con un `randomElement`, como le indico en la factory.

Por qué ocurre esto? Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente forma

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $satisfaccion = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        factory (Operator::class, 20)->create();
        $customers = factory (Customer::class, 300)->create();
        factory (Tour::class, 100)
        ->create()
            ->each(function ($tour) use ($customers)
                {
                    $tour->customers()
                        ->attach($customers
                            ->random(mt_rand(10, 40))
                            ->pluck('id'), 
                             ['satisfaccion' => $satisfaccion[array_rand($satisfaccion)]]
                        );
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Creo que es mejor que pases directamente en el attach el valor del campo satisfaccion

Comment: Hola. Te agradezco tu idea. Ya la había probado pero no es válida. En primer lugar, hay que inyectar Faker en el método run. Eso no es el problema. El problema es que no coge un randomElement para cada relación, sino para cada objeto Tour. Así, todas las relaciones de un viaje tienen el mismo valor de satisfacción, lo que no es el objetivo. Cada relación debería tener un valor aleatorio.
De todos modos, gracias.

Comment: Cambia el randomElement por el array_rand, modifique la respuesta usando esta función de PHP, te dejo el enlace de la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Que pena, se me olvido agregar el Array, deberías probar esta solución, debería ser mas rápido el seed de esta forma.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución, que publico por si a alguien le sirve.
Se trata de rellenar el campo satisfacion de la tabla pivote con NULL, y luego, en el mismo seeder, usar el Query Buider para generar valores aleatorios en cada registro de la tabla pivote. El código del seeder queda así:

```
<?php

use App\Operator;
use App\Tour;
use App\Customer;
use App\CustomerTour;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(Faker $faker)
    {
        factory (Operator::class, 20)->create();
        $customers = factory (Customer::class, 300)->create();
        factory (Tour::class, 100)
        ->create()
            ->each(function ($tour) use ($customers)
                {
                    $tour->customers()
                        ->attach($customers
                            ->random(mt_rand(10, 40))
                            ->pluck('id')
                        );
                }
            );
        $relaciones = DB::table('customer_tour')->get();
        foreach ($relaciones as $relacion) {
            $relacion->satisfaccion = $faker->randomElement(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);
            DB::table('customer_tour')
                ->where('id', $relacion->id)
                ->update(['satisfaccion' => $relacion->satisfaccion]);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que a alguno os resulte tan buena solución como me ha resultado a mí.

Un saludo.